# Inserting data into database but getting incorrect syntax error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add student data into a database but keeps coming up with the error "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'". I'm very new to using windows form does anybody know where I have gone wrong?

```
private void BTAddstudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string myconnection = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\tayla\OneDrive\Documents\StudentPerformance\StudentPerformance\Studentdatabase.mdf; Integrated Security = True";

        string Query = "Insert Into Table (ID, First name, Last name, Course 1, Course 2, Course 3, Course 4, Course 5, Course 6, Course 7, Course 8, Course 9, Course 10) values('" + this.txtbxID.Text + "','" + this.txtbxfirstname.Text + "','" + this.txtbxlastname.Text + "','" + this.txtbxcourse1.Text
            + "','" + this.txtbxcourse2.Text + "','" + this.txtbxcourse3.Text + "','" + this.txtbxcourse4.Text + "','" + this.txtbxcourse5.Text + "','" + this.txtbxcourse6.Text + "','" + this.txtbxcourse7.Text
            + "','" + this.txtbxcourse8.Text + "','" + this.txtbxcourse9.Text + "','" + this.txtbxcourse10.Text + "')";

        SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(myconnection);
        SqlCommand mycom = new SqlCommand(Query, myconn);
        SqlDataReader reader1;
        myconn.Open();
        reader1 = mycom.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader1.Read()) ;
        {
        }
        myconn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a parameterised query, if you don't know what that is, you need to research it, it will make it easier to spot mistakes, and it will stop sql injection attacks among other things

Comment: Ok thank you I will look it up.

Comment: The ten courses may also indicate to rethink your design. Usually there should be another table, where you insert rows for the courses people take.

Answer (score 1):

If you named your table `Table`, you must use brackets because Table is a reserved word. You must also use brackets in your column names if you use spaces.

Your sql statement should be like this:

```
Insert Into [Table] (ID, [First name], [Last name], [Course 1], [Course 2], ...
```

Using parameterized query is better. It's easier to read and it prevents SQL injection attack.